# Tax breakdown for bonus income

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, 401k, bonus

Say the bonus is $8000 and $6800 are set for a 401k (pre-tax) deduction. Here's the tax breakdown. Does this look right? Shouldn't the taxes be calculated on the $1200? ($8000 minus $6800 due to pre-tax 401k contribution)

[image]

Comment: Not an answer because I'm not certain, but looks like the federal taxes are quite low (~22% of your 1.2k net income), and it is the other lines with higher contributions. Are social security etc. payments made based on gross income instead of net income?

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon Looks like 22% is applied on $8000 instead of $6800 in this case!

Comment: Fed taxes are $264, which is the federal taxes payable; see answer below for detailed answer in line with what I was suggesting might be the case.

Answer (score 6):

Social security and medicare taxes are [still levied on 401k contributions](https://ttlc.intuit.com/community/retirement/discussion/are-contributions-to-401k-plans-subject-to-fica-and-medicare/00/30372#) at a total of 7.65%. Looking at your table, ($496 + $116)/$8,000 = 7.65%.

Federal taxes were 22% of $1,200 (0.22 x $1200 = $264) which is [inline with IRS rules](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p15#en_US_2020_publink1000202354), as pointed out by users in the comments. State taxes look like they are levied on the $1,200 as you expected. But, you can look up the corresponding rates and check the numbers to be sure.

Comment: Specifically, fed tax is 22% of taxable income which is correct for bonus income in 2020

Comment: To @DStanley's point, here's where it says that: https://www.irs.gov/publications/p15#en_US_2020_publink1000202354

Comment: Good stuff, added to the answer.

Comment: Should these taxes be applied on $8000 or the $6800?

Comment: @user6123723 which ones? Social security and medicare are both applied to the total $8,000.